# adding line breaks and headers in django's admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

EDIT: If you are going to give a downvote, at least explain why -.-
Also, read comments if my post is still unclear. I tried to explain it a bit more in the comments but if it is still unclear about what I'm saying, let me know and I will take printscreens and explain using images.

I have created a model like so

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title_of_post = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    actual_post = models.TextField()
```

and I put this model in the admin interface and enabled the admin interface. Now, when I go to 127.0.0.1/admin/ and sign in, I can add this model. The posts created in the Post model can be seen on the homepage (127.0.0.1) so say my "title_of_post" is "title" and my "actual_post" is "the actual post", if I go to 127.0.0.1 I can see both the title and actual post on the homepage. The problem is, when I am in the admin interface and in the actual_post text box / TextField section, suppose I write this.

```
Something.
else
```

It would not recognize that I pushed the enter key after the period. I tried

```
Something. <br>
else
```

but that also didn't work. It does not go on a new line after the period. Is there any way to go to the next line when inputting information from the text box / TextField in the django admin interface? Is there any way to put headers from the admin interface, not from the template? Essentially, I want to be able to create this html from the admin interface.

```
<h1>Something.</h1> <br>
else
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not the guy that downvoted you, but its kinda blur what you need, so I'm going to ask you a question to clear it out: You want to write html inside Post.actual_post and then display it on the home page?

Comment: Hm okay, so you know when you sign into the admin interface? when you got o 127.0.0.1/admin/? and then your models appear there, and my Post model appears there. I then have the option to add a Post or edit or delete a Post. When I click 'add' to add a Post, it takes me to another page which says "Title of post:" followed by a CharField, and "Actual post:" followed by a TextField. When I write in the text field, even though I hit the tab button to indent, or hit the return key to create a new line, when I submit the post and go to my actual website, there are no indents or new lines.

Comment: @GuilhermeDaviddaCosta , there are no indents or new lines, everything is just in one paragraph even though when I typed it out in the admin interface, I used indents (pushed the tab key) and created new lines by pressing the return key... do you get what I mean now? Or should I printscreen images and show you?

Comment: Basically, I create blogs for clients. I told the client that if he wants to update the blog, he just needs to go to his-Site.com/admin/, sign in, and then click 'add Post' and then type in the title of the post and the body of the post and hit enter, and then the site will automatically update, which it does. However, when he types in his post in the admin interface, he indents using the tab key and creates new lines using the return key, and after he  creates the post and then goes to the actual site to see the post, the post doesn't have any indents or line breaks on the actual site.

Comment: on the actual site. Even though in the admin interface when he typed out the blog post, he used indents and line breaks.

Comment: Well, simple idents or newlines wont work with html. Unless you use a <pre> tag.

Comment: @GuilhermeDaviddaCosta Right, simple indents or new lines wont work with html. I then asked the client to type out his post in the admin interface, and whenever he wants a new line, I told him to type in <br /> and he did and that didn't work either. After he typed in the <br /> and submitted his post through the admin interface and went to look at the websites, there was no line break, however, the actual letters '<br />' appeared. Is there any way to create line breaks and new lines through the admin interface when submitting in information through a TextField?

Comment: As I told you in my answer, you need to use the safe template filter. Otherwise, django will escape the html tag special characters and will print as a useless string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to show html inside a property, you need to place like this in your template:

```
{{ post.actual_post|safe }}
```

the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-safe) template filter its good for not escaping html tags inside your template.

And this will print as:

```
Something
else
```

intead of:

```
Something <br /> else
```